# How to optimize text output in if/ else for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

```
def statistic():
    if db.session.query(func.count(Exchange.exchange_id)).filter_by(user_id=g.user.user_id).scalar() == 0:
        text_info = '(big test message 1)'
    else:
        text_info = '(big  message 2)'

    return render_template('console/statistic.html', text_info=text_info)
```

Hello, I'm using Python 3.6 + Flask. I output texts from the variable `text_info` on the 5 pages. But the text is large and looks awful in the code. How can I optimize and minimize the output in `text_info`? Open from file? What can you tell? thanks

Comment: text.head(5) or text.tail(5) (5 first or last lines)

Answer (score 0):

**the easiest way**

You might indeed load the text from files:

```py
(...)
with open('file_one.txt') as file:
    text_info = file.read()
(...)
```

Please note, however, that you'd end up adding a [context manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) / `with` expression for each message you want to have in the app and probably you'd have to create `N files for N messages`...

---

**the proper way**

You can prepare a simple config for the app (for this example I will use TOML, let's say the filename is `config.toml`):

```
[strings]
first = "my first big string"
second = "my second big string"
```

and then you can consume it as follows:

```py
import pytoml # you can install it using pip

(...)
with open('config.toml', 'rb') as config:
    cfg = pytoml.loads(config.read())

string1 = cfg['strings']['first']
string2 = cfg['strings']['second']
(...)
```

---

Remember, hardcoding values is not a great idea in general. In a real-world app, you'd end up either using a config file of some kind (yaml/toml/ini/properties/other) or getting these values as a result of some API call.